# When can we use Simple Binary Tree over Binary Search Tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Lots of tutorials focus on implementation of Binary Search Tree and it is easier for search operations. Are there applications or circumstances where implementing a Simple Binary Tree is better than BST? Or is it just taught as an introductory concept for trees?

Comment: What is simple binary tree and how it differs from bst?

Comment: A binary search tree is where the left node is less than the root node and the right node is greater than root node throughout the tree. By simple binary tree i'm referring to a regular tree that doesn't represent data like BST. For example, data inserted level-wise.

Comment: Actually I have not heard "simple binary tree" before because it looks like a plain tree with number of children limitation. So it could be useful if you want to represent any hierarchy with no more than 2 children in each node. I do not think it is any better than plain tree (at least on small datasets - maybe it could be useful in some specific case when you want to optimize memory or speed by reducing cache misses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a binary tree (rather than a binary search tree) when you have a structure that requires a parent and up to two children. For example, consider a tree to represent mathematical expressions. The expression `(a+b)*c` becomes:

```
                *
              /   \
             +     c
           /   \
          a     b
```

The [Paring heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap) is a data structure that is *logically* a general tree (i.e. no restriction on the number of children a node can have), but it is often implemented using a [left-child right-sibling binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree). The LCRS binary tree is often more efficient and easier to work with than a general tree.

The [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) also is a binary tree, but not a binary search tree.

The old guessing game where the player answers a bunch of yes/no questions in order to arrive at an answer, is another example of a binary tree. In the tree below, the left child is the "No" answer, and the right child is "Yes" answer

```
                           Is it an animal?
                        /                    \
                 Is it a plant?          Is is a mammal?
                                         /            \
                                     A reptile?      A dog?
```

You can imagine an arbitrarily deep tree with questions at each level.

Those are just a few examples. I've found binary trees useful in lots of different situations.